# How I can be alerted if an application is not running in Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a critical application that I *need* to have it running on my server.

Unfortunately it's poorly coded and it keeps crashing.
If it's not running it's a big problem, but I can't use a [simple application monitor like this](http://www.jockersoft.com/english/appmonitor_index.php) because if the app crashes I need to input the configuration again - so I can't just run it again, I have to RDP into the server and manually start it again.

So I need a monitor that sends me an email if the process has been stopped.
Anyone knows a program that can do that job? I couldn't find it

Answer (score 1):

You could set a scheduled task that runs a powershell script every n minutes to check for the presence of the process and email you if it cannot find it.